# C# MongoDB.Driver 2.2. - Usage of GridFs

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I 've used the GridFs functions with the legacy mongo db c# driver in the following way.

```
var file = Database.GridFS.FindOne(Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(file.Id)));
```

The MongoDb C# 2.1 driver, implements GridFs in an other way, could somebody show me please an example? I've found no documentation yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The .NET driver documentation has a detailed guide on using GridFS. http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/gridfs/

Comment: i know the question point only to gridfs, but as the mongodb it self says, for under 16mb we shouldn't use gridfs, and most of the file including the images that we want to share on internet( not the one we want to sell and print at the size of a building) fall on the category of below 16 mb, can you show a sample without gridfs? to store and read data from mongo?

Comment: Just use a byte array... MongoDB supports a binary type.